# Checkout form looks terrible

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css

Im currently building my first ever wordpress theme however the checkout form just looks messy. I have tried changing some bits around with css but It all just looks our of line.

[image: screenshot]

I have tried changing the css styles for the form but it wont line up for my attempts by using margins and positions yet sadly no luck. Any help would be great :D

Comment: you need to figure out what styles are causing the issues and then how specific are the selectors so you can override them.  Use the inspector to debug this issue, it may take a while of looking through elements to find the right one and figure out what styles are the culprits but it's very doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there's a CSS conflict with your theme or another plugin.

To troubleshoot the issue, deactivate each plugin, one at a time, to establish which one may be causing the problem. If that doesn't work, activate a different theme to see if that solves it.

If it's your theme causing the issues, you'll need to use your browsers developer tools to identify which CSS is responsible. You can then override it via your own CSS.

Alternatively, try and add this line to functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );
```

This will strip all styles from WooCommerce so you can build your own.

This is how I usually tackle WooCommerce styling as it allows me to have full control of the design. It's time consuming, but you can re-use your styles for future builds.

Comment: Hey Sam! Thanks so much for helping me out. Id still like to use the current styles so I can't deactivate it sadly. However I did try your second suggestion of deactivating the plugins 1 by 1 and that still has not solved the issue. :)

Comment: No worries @Brandon. Maybe test a different theme to see if the layout still looks bad? It's very difficult to troubleshoot as every theme is built differently. I suspect it's something in your current theme that is causing a conflict. To fix it, you'll need to find the problematic CSS and override it. I've updated my answer.